# Not able to see the spring batch db queries in dynatrace

Tags: spring-batch, dynatrace

In my spring batch project i am reading data from db and write data to db, when i checked the dynatrace after job completed, i am not able to see the db select and insert queries in dynatrace.

Is any configuration need to do in spring batch to get these queries in dynatrace ?

Thanks!

Comment: what database do you have and what do you use to access it in your application?